# TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to output the content of data[0] with jQuery but I have this error

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.

Any ideas?

```
$('<div>').append(function () {

    if (data[0].length != 0) {
        var $container = $('<div></div>');
        $.each(data[0], function(val) {
            $container.append(
                $('<div>').html(data[val][0]),
                $('<div>').html(data[val][1]),
                $('<div>').html(data[val][2])
            )
        });
        return $container.html();
    }

})
```

Comment: Add a console.log($container.html()) before the return statement, what do you get?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Are you sure it is coming from this location? It seems like this piece of code does not cause this problem.

Comment: You don't return anything in the `else` condition

Comment: Maybe $container.html() returned a string not an object?

Comment: Throw in a ton of console.logs to make sure all your assumptions about your code are correct.

Comment: It doesn't need to return anything to work. It won't cause the shown error.

Comment: This will never work.  you're referencing each index of `data[0]` (e.g. `data[0][0]`, `data[0][1]`), as an index in data (e.g. `data[0]`, `data[1]`).  Because data[0] has a length of *n* doesn't mean data also has a length of *n*.

Comment: Show the contents of data if you want this to be fixable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably .html(data[0][val][0])? give an example of data object.

Comment: This guy gave me idea how to solve the issue was forgotting to put the [0] in the array                 $('<div>').html(data[0][val][0]), this does work, sorry for this post, i'm really exhausted...

Comment: sometimes we need yet another eye ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try returning an empty string if the data doesn't have length

```
$('<div>').append(function () {

    if (data[0].length != 0) {
        var $container = $('<div></div>');
        $.each(data[0], function(val) {
            $container.append(
                $('<div>').html(data[val][0]),
                $('<div>').html(data[val][1]),
                $('<div>').html(data[val][2])
            )
        });
        return $container.html();
    }
    return '';    
});
```

from append docs when using function:

> A function that returns an HTML string, DOM element(s), or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element

I believe the issue may be related to nothing being returned and the parser not being able to determine type

Comment: Sorry, does not work :(

Comment: then need to reproduce your issue in a demo sandbox like jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have upvoted you for the help but i'm really for disrupting you, because my issue was really stupid ... the issue was forgotting to put the [0] in the array $('<div>').html(data[0][val][0]), this does work, sorry for this post, i'm really exhausted